# Connected sum of two "same" Klein bottles

Tags: geometric-topology, klein-bottle

If I take sphere and remove two open disks from it and on the boundary of that space I make identification like on the picture, what do I get? Are both of those objects Klein's bottles?

This is what I want: [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFO7k.png)

Comment: Klein bottles are manifolds without boundary.  Your words and diagram do not illustrate what you mean by "edge words" or "same edges".

Comment: @hardmath I edited post. I hope that is clear now what has to be done.

Answer (score 0):

A $2$-sphere with two disks removed is homeomorphic to a cylinder $I\times S^1$.

If I understand your picture correct you now want to identify the two boundary components of this cylinder. In the way it is pictured you get a [Klein bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle).

Comment: Yes.I was thinking the same. For the moment i wasn't sure but when i checked, they have same fundamental group so they are homeomorphic. Can i picture "making of this object" as torus being made from two removed disks on sphere but twisted at some point?